# split strings to different columns based on semicolon

Tags: r

My data is like this

```
dff<- structure(c(7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"P42356;Q8N8J0;A4QPH2", "P67809;Q9Y2T7", "Q08554", "Q13835", 
"Q5T749", "Q9NZT1"), class = "factor")
```

I try to split my strings and make them in different columns

for example the output should look like this

```
 A       B        C        
Q9NZT1
Q5T749
Q13835
Q08554  
P67809   Q9Y2T7 
P42356   Q8N8J0   A4QPH2
```

I tried to use strsplit but it did not work.

```
unlist(strsplit(dff, ";", fixed = TRUE))
```

Thanks to @thepule I try to make a rule. each string is first stays on the same column it is. if it is separated with a ; then it moves to the next column but stays in the same row

Comment: @thepule good question. each string met first stays on the same column it is. if it is separated with a ; then it moves to the next column , is it clear?

Comment: @user5249203 I have tried those answers , did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, looks like I am the only one using basic feature of R.

```
x <- strsplit(as.character(dff), ";")
l <- lengths(x)  ## R 3.3.0 onward
m <- max(l)
x <- t(sapply(x[as.logical(l)], function(a) c(a, rep("",m-length(a)))))

x
#      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
# [1,] "Q9NZT1" ""       ""      
# [2,] "Q5T749" ""       ""      
# [3,] "Q13835" ""       ""      
# [4,] "Q08554" ""       ""      
# [5,] "P67809" "Q9Y2T7" ""      
# [6,] "P42356" "Q8N8J0" "A4QPH2"
```

If you want a data frame, just coerce this matrix into a data frame by `as.data.frame(x)`:

```
#       V1     V2     V3
# 1 Q9NZT1              
# 2 Q5T749              
# 3 Q13835              
# 4 Q08554              
# 5 P67809 Q9Y2T7       
# 6 P42356 Q8N8J0 A4QPH2
```

---

**Follow-up**

Regarding your later request, we can do:

```
x <- strsplit(as.character(dff), ";")
ind <- as.logical(l <- lengths(x))  ## R 3.3.0 onward
m <- max(l <- l[ind])
x <- t(sapply(x[ind], function(a) c(paste(a,1:length(a),sep="_"), rep("",m-length(a)))))
ind <- l==1L; x[ind,1] <- gsub("_1","",x[ind,1])

#      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      
# [1,] "Q9NZT1"   ""         ""        
# [2,] "Q5T749"   ""         ""        
# [3,] "Q13835"   ""         ""        
# [4,] "Q08554"   ""         ""        
# [5,] "P67809_1" "Q9Y2T7_2" ""        
# [6,] "P42356_1" "Q8N8J0_2" "A4QPH2_3"
```

Again, use `as.data.frame` if you want a data frame. I finally use one `gsub`, because I don't want to use `if...else` or `ifelse` inside `sapply`, which will increase the R interpretation overhead.

Comment: I want to know if you know how I can make put those that are separated with; in a separate cell?

Answer (score 3):

I love the **splitstackshape** package for these gnarly type data:

```
dff<- c("", "P42356;Q8N8J0;A4QPH2", "P67809;Q9Y2T7", "Q08554", "Q13835", 
"Q5T749", "Q9NZT1")

library(splitstackshape)

cSplit(data.frame(dff), 'dff', ";")

#     dff_1  dff_2  dff_3
# 1:     NA     NA     NA
# 2: P42356 Q8N8J0 A4QPH2
# 3: P67809 Q9Y2T7     NA
# 4: Q08554     NA     NA
# 5: Q13835     NA     NA
# 6: Q5T749     NA     NA
# 7: Q9NZT1     NA     NA
```

Comment: close but those that are moved to new column should stay in the same row

Comment: I don't understand your logic but could probably be done with a row sum on non `NA` values with a sort.

Comment: I added a logic above in my question. I think your solution is good but only upside down :-D look at the string on 7 row, in my output that one is 1 row. look at the 6th , that one in my output is the second etc

Comment: Is there a specific need to use `pacman`? Seems unnecessary here. (For those who aren't familiar with `pacman`, `p_load` is equivalent to `library`.)

Comment: I think you can pass `cSplit()` a data frame, if I'm not mistaken. It will coerce.

Comment: What's the difference between your code and `if (! require("splitstackshape")) install.packages("splitstackshape")`?

Comment: You'd still need a call to library after that to load the package if they don't have it installed.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a data frame from your vector and then separate it:

```
tidyr::separate(data.frame(text = dff), text, into = c("A", "B", "C"), sep = ";", fill = "right", extra = "drop")
       A      B      C
1 Q9NZT1   <NA>   <NA>
2 Q5T749   <NA>   <NA>
3 Q13835   <NA>   <NA>
4 Q08554   <NA>   <NA>
5 P67809 Q9Y2T7   <NA>
6 P42356 Q8N8J0 A4QPH2
```

*Data*:

```
c("Q9NZT1", "Q5T749", "Q13835", "Q08554", "P67809;Q9Y2T7", "P42356;Q8N8J0;A4QPH2"
)
```

Comment: nice but it is in a case if I know that I have only three strings in advance so that I can set them to A, B and C but if I don't know and or if there are many , then it will create so many NAs at the end too , no ?

Comment: Yes. If you don't know very much about your text, you'd better write your own parser as others have done. But if you know the maximum columns you have or you want to keep, this would be nice method.

Comment: `cSplit(as.data.frame(dff), "dff", sep=";", drop=TRUE)` works for me

Comment: @PierreLafortune Didn't use that package very often, but I believe it works.

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune you are right! it works but add NAs at the end,

Comment: I'm sorry @Psidom I didn't mean to post that under your answer

Comment: @nik That is not an indication that the method does not work. We did the hard part, you can be bothered to do `res[is.na(res)] <- ""`. There's no reason to further question people's efforts over something as silly as your choice of missing value indicator

Answer (score 1):

I have another extremely super brutal solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

list <- lapply(str_split(dff, ";"), function(x) {
        if(x[1] != "") data.frame(lapply(x, data.frame), stringsAsFactors = F)
})

list <- list[!sapply(list, is.null)]
final <- bind_rows(list)

final
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]

  X..i.. X..i...1 X..i...2
   (chr)    (chr)   (fctr)
1 Q9NZT1       NA       NA
2 Q5T749       NA       NA
3 Q13835       NA       NA
4 Q08554       NA       NA
5 P67809   Q9Y2T7       NA
6 P42356   Q8N8J0   A4QPH2
```

Comment: @hepule nice, complicated to visualise it for me :-) but nice solution :-)

Comment: @nik yeah it was more for the fun of it :P

Comment: I liked your solution for its beauty :-D

Comment: Haha much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

you were going in right direction (if it is not for factors), `strsplit`expects character vector and when a list is generated, all you  need to is rbind them.

```
***With your input data***
# Not sure why you want them as factors
```

This still works...

```
my_list <-  strsplit(as.character(dff), ';')

require(plyr)
res<- ldply(my_list ,rbind)
```

output

```
   1      2      3
1 Q9NZT1   <NA>   <NA>
2 Q5T749   <NA>   <NA>
3 Q13835   <NA>   <NA>
4 Q08554   <NA>   <NA>
5 P67809 Q9Y2T7   <NA>
6 P42356 Q8N8J0 A4QPH2
```

Comment: you changed the original dff to label to be able to pass it to strsplit ? funny ! thanks still your solution is upside down ! look at my question

Comment: I did not understand. Is the data input wrong ? The output is what you wanted right ?

Comment: I liked your answer too,

Answer (score 1):

```
library(splitstackshape)
res <- cSplit(data.frame(dff), "dff", sep=";", drop=TRUE)
```

That is all you need. But if NA's scare you:

```
res[] <- lapply(res, as.character)
res[is.na(res)] <- ''
```

Comment: oh it works, I made a typo, one question do you know how to stop column naming it ? my mean just not generating any column names when using your function ?

Comment: No but you can remove them after 'names(res) <- NULL'

Answer (score 1):

you can also use *str_split* which vectorised over string and pattern,thus, you don't need to covert it to character

```
library(plyr)
library(stringr)
x <- str_split(dff, ";")
res<- ldply(x ,bind)
#       1      2      3
#1 Q9NZT1   <NA>   <NA>
#2 Q5T749   <NA>   <NA>
#3 Q13835   <NA>   <NA>
#4 Q08554   <NA>   <NA>
#5 P67809 Q9Y2T7   <NA>
#6 P42356 Q8N8J0 A4QPH2
#7          <NA>   <NA>
#8          <NA>   <NA>
#9          <NA>   <NA>
```